# ERROR:: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

**Error::1452:** `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`findmybuffet`.`det_res_item_selected`, CONSTRAINT`fk_det_res_item_selected_Buf_Off_Id1`FOREIGN KEY (`Buf_Off_Id`) REFERENCES`mas_buf_off`(`Buf_Off_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)`

---

***I have three tables below***::

det_res_item_selected is throwing error when i tried to create the table

**How can i resolve this ?**

---

```
CREATE TABLE `det_res_item_selected` (
  `Line_Selected_Item_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Item_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Item_Selected` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `Buf_Off_Id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Item_Image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Line_Selected_Item_Id`),
  KEY `fk_det_res_item_selected_Item1_Idx` (`Item_Id`),
  KEY `fk_det_res_item_selected_Buf_Off_Id1_Idx` (`Buf_Off_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_det_res_item_selected_Buf_Off_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Buf_Off_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_buf_off` (`Buf_Off_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_det_res_item_selected_Item_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Item_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_item` (`Item_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `mas_buf_off` (
  `Buf_Off_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Buf_Type_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `From_Time` time NOT NULL,
  `To_Time` time NOT NULL,
  `Res_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Buf_Off_Id`),
  KEY `fk_mas_buf_off_Buf_Type_Id1_Idx` (`Buf_Type_Id`),
  KEY `fk_mas_buf_off_Res_Id1_Idx` (`Res_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mas_buf_off_Buf_Type_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Buf_Type_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_buf_type` (`Buf_Type_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mas_buf_off_Res_Id1_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Res_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_restaurant` (`Res_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `mas_restaurant` (
  `Res_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Res_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Res_Featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Res_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Which of those 3 queries is causing error? Or is it some other query?

Comment: det_res_item_selected is throwing error when i tried to create the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just ran below script and it worked on my system.

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;

CREATE TABLE `det_res_item_selected` (

  `Line_Selected_Item_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Item_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `Item_Selected` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',

  `Buf_Off_Id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,

  `Item_Image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Line_Selected_Item_Id`),

  KEY `fk_det_res_item_selected_Item1_Idx` (`Item_Id`),

  KEY `fk_det_res_item_selected_Buf_Off_Id1_Idx` (`Buf_Off_Id`),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_det_res_item_selected_Buf_Off_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Buf_Off_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_buf_off` (`Buf_Off_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_det_res_item_selected_Item_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Item_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_item` (`Item_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `mas_buf_off` (

  `Buf_Off_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Buf_Type_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `From_Time` time NOT NULL,

  `To_Time` time NOT NULL,

  `Res_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Buf_Off_Id`),

  KEY `fk_mas_buf_off_Buf_Type_Id1_Idx` (`Buf_Type_Id`),

  KEY `fk_mas_buf_off_Res_Id1_Idx` (`Res_Id`),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_mas_buf_off_Buf_Type_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Buf_Type_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_buf_type` (`Buf_Type_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_mas_buf_off_Res_Id1_Id1` FOREIGN KEY (`Res_Id`) REFERENCES `mas_restaurant` (`Res_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `mas_restaurant` (

  `Res_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Res_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

  `Res_Featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  PRIMARY KEY (`Res_Id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

set foreign_key_checks=1;
```